# Delphi XE2/2007 and LibXML

Tags: delphi, libxml2

IDEs on separate machines both WinXP. The versions/date of `LibXML2.dll` vary in both machines from 2010 to 2012.

I am installing `libxml2.pas` from SourceForge (2.7.3) I created 3 apps, a console and a VCL Forms on XE2 and a VCL Forms on D2007.

If I do not reference a function in the `Libxml2.dll` my app runs, if I reference a function
e.g. `Doc:=xxmlParseFile(xnldocptr)` the app crashes at start up in `InitUnits`.

```
program Project25;

uses
  Forms,

      Unit26 in 'Unit26.pas' {Form26};

    {$R *.res}


begin<---------- Access violation here
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm26, Form26);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

[image: AV Message]

//Main Firm
    uses Libxml2;

```
{$R *.dfm} 

procedure TForm26.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); var Doc: xmlDocPtr; 
begin 
 Doc:=xmlParseFile('c:\a.xml'); 
 xmlFreeDoc(Doc); 
end
```

I can see that the module LibXML2 has been loaded.

Am I doing something silly or missing something?

Comment: uses Libxml2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm26.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: xmlDocPtr;
begin
  Doc:=xmlParseFile('c:\a.xml');
  xmlFreeDoc(Doc);
end;

Comment: You do realize that Doc can be nil if a.xml is not welformed? Can you edit your question and add the EXACT error you are receiving?

Comment: Your missing a point yje app never reaches this code  ub dor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LIBXML2.DLL` itself depends on 2 other DLL's: `ICONV.DLL` and `ZLIB1.DLL`

You can download the latest version of these dll's [here](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/)

Make sure that these DLL's reside on the same path as your delphi executable.

I have tested your project under W7/Delphi XE and I don't receive an AV.

Comment: Progress but not quite there.  Dependency Walker showed thtat MSVCR90.dll was missing. XE2 machine is working .Thx.